# Is it possible that $\delta$ is always equal to $\varepsilon$ when the function of given limit has identical roots?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Warning : it's slightly stupid for a question, but i just want to assure it.

Given question :

$$\lim_{z \to 2i} \frac{z^2+4}{z-2i}=4i$$

My proof :

$$\forall \varepsilon\gt 0,\, \exists \delta\gt 0, \ni \, 0\lt  \left|z-2i \right|\lt \delta \Rightarrow \left|\frac{z^2+4}{z-2i} - 4i \right|\lt \varepsilon$$
Sketch work :
For $z\ne 2i$

$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{z^2+4}{z-2i} - 4i \right| 
&=\left|\frac{z^2-4iz-4}{z-2i}\right| \\
&=\left|\frac{(z-2i)(z-2i)}{z-2i}\right| \\
&=\left|z-2i \right| \\
&\lt \varepsilon \\
\text{Set } \left|z-2i\right|\lt \varepsilon \text{ to be equal to } \delta, \text{ we conclude that } \varepsilon = \delta
\end{align}$

Formal Proof:

Given $\varepsilon \gt 0$, choose $\delta = \varepsilon$ such that for $z\ne 2i$ we have the following:

Assume $0\lt \left|z-2i\right|\lt \delta$
$\begin{align}
\Rightarrow\left|\frac{z^2+4}{z-2i} - 4i\right|
&=\left|\frac{z^2-4iz-4}{z-2i}\right| \\
&=\left|\frac{(z-2i)(z-2i)}{z-2i}\right| \\
&=|z-2i|\\
&\lt \delta \\
&= \varepsilon
\end{align}$

It's weird to get $\delta = \varepsilon$ when usually i got $\delta$ is multiple of $\varepsilon$.
Is there anything wrong with my proof? If it isn't, could i conclude that "if we have a rational function with the numerator is a quadratic function that has two identical roots and the denominator is its factor and the difference of $z$ and $z_0$ is equal to the denominator, then if we wanna proof this limit, we have always get $\delta = \varepsilon$" ?

If you don't understand what i mean on the setence above, here is another example that i've tried and i got $\delta = \varepsilon$

$$\lim_{z \to i} \frac{z^2+1}{z-i}=2i$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, roots of the numerator are $2i$ and $-2i$ and for second example,
roots are $i$ and $-i$.

So correct formulation is:

"If we have a rational function with the numerator is a quadratic function that has two roots **which are negatives of each other** and the denominator is its factor and the difference of $z$ and $z_0$ is equal to the denominator, then if we wanna proof this limit, we have always get $\delta=\epsilon$."

To verify this solve general example,
$$\lim_{z \to a} \frac{z^2- a^2}{z-a}= 2a$$
where $a$ is any complex number.

Comment: Hmmm.. actually my explanation isn't good. I mean, if we *already* combine the function with *L*, and all terms satisfiy with what i'm talking before... sorry for the mistake. Anyway, out of it... is that mean you agree with me that in this case $\delta=\varepsilon$?

Comment: Yes! To verify this fact solve general example given above.